# Calling a functor from a Cuda Kernel

Tags: c++, cuda

I am trying to call a functor from a Cuda Kernel. The functor is given by the programmer and my library uses it to perform some functions and returns the processed array.

**Since the functor is in Host Memory Space, I am Copying the object to Device and using the functor in my kernel call.**

Error : It says the Functor operator() is inaccessible from the kernel.'

I cannot understand where I am Wrong.

Note : Full Error Message dumped At the end.

Here is the Full Code :

```
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

class my_functor
{

        __device__
        int operator() (int x)
        {
                return x*10;
        }
};



template <class T,typename Func>
    __global__
void for_each_kernel (T* d_v,int N,Func f)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int num_threads = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;

    __shared__ T s_x[1024];

    for(int i = idx; i < N; i += num_threads)
    {

        s_x[threadIdx.x] = d_v[i];

        // Call The Functor Here
        s_x[threadIdx.x] = f (s_x[threadIdx.x]);

        d_v[i] = s_x[threadIdx.x];
    }
}

template <class T>
class device_vector
{
    T *d_v;
    int numEle;

    public :

    device_vector (T *h_v,int N)
    {
        cudaMalloc  ((T**)&d_v,N*sizeof(T));
        cudaMemcpy(d_v, h_v, N * sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        numEle = N;


    }

    void set (T data,int index)
    {
        cudaMemcpy (&d_v[index],&data,sizeof(T),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    }


    T get (int index)
    {
        T temp;
        cudaMemcpy (&temp,&d_v[index],sizeof(T),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        return temp;
    }


    // Only Provide Start And End Vertices Fot Which you Want To Do Some Operation
    template <typename Func>
        void for_each (int start,int end,Func f)
        {

            Func *new_func;

            cudaMalloc (&new_func,sizeof(my_functor));
            cudaMemcpy (new_func,&f,sizeof (my_functor),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);    

            for_each_kernel<<<26,1024>>> (d_v,end-start+1,*new_func);   
        }   

};


int a[1<<28];
int main ()
{
    int N = 1<<28;

    my_functor functor; 

    for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
        a[i] = i;

    device_vector<int> d (a,N);

    d.for_each (0,N-1,functor);

    printf ("Getting Element At Index %d : %d \n",100,d.get(100));

    return 0;
}
```

Error  Message Dump :

```
device_vector.cu(40): error: function "my_functor::operator()"
(18): here is inaccessible
          detected during:
            instantiation of "void for_each_kernel(T *, int, Func) [with T=int, Func=my_functor]" 
(107): here
            instantiation of "void device_vector<T>::for_each(int, int, Func) [with T=int, Func=my_functor]" 
(125): here

1 error detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00005da2_00000000-9_device_vector.cpp1.ii".
```

Comment: @talonmies is this a better way to put forth my problem....?

Comment: You should really learn more about C++ before you proceed to an advanced topics, such as GPU-accelerated computing. Check out this thread: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the inaccessible error because `my_functor` is a class. Class members are, by default, *private*. If you change your definition of `my_functor`like this:

```
class my_functor
{
        public:
        __device__
        int operator() (int x)
        {
                return x*10;
        }
};
```

or change it to a struct (note struct members are public by default):

```
struct my_functor
{

        __device__
        int operator() (int x)
        {
                return x*10;
        }
};
```

you might find the code compiles. There are possibly other things wrong with the code, but either of these modifications should remove the source of that particular compilation error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time.